# Forced to iterate over Collection<String> using Object?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, collections, java-8, intellij-17

All of a sudden, [[image]intellij-idea](/questions/tagged/intellij-idea) 2017.1.5 does not allow me to iterate over a `Collection<String>` with a `forach` and a `String` variable.

The simple piece of code:

```
for (String methodPath : methodsService.getMethodPaths()) {
    // ....
}
```

where

```
private Map<String, MethodMeta> methods = new HashMap<>();

public Collection<String> getMethodPaths() {
    return this.methods.keySet();
}
```

is marked as error with the suggestion to change the variable `methodPath` from `String` to `Object`.

At the beginning, I thought the IDE was just indexing and the error for some later-edited code was still appearing, which wouldn't bother me as much, but it actually  **does not compile** the project:

> Compile error during compilation with javac.
>
> C:\workspace...\MyFileName.java:23
>
> error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String

I'm using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) version 131.

[image: project configuration]

Restarting the PC, does not make the error disappear.

Comment: What's the type of `methodsService`?

Comment: Show the declaration of `methodsService`. It sounds like you've declared it as a raw type.

Comment: In those situation, you should provide a [mcve] that reproduce this. How can I know that you are not implementing an interface that use legacy code ?

Comment: `methodsService != methods`

Comment: I suspect the IDE is cursed, but I've been known to be wrong.

Comment: @AndyTurner right. `MethodsService methodsService = ...` had to be instantiated as `MethodsService<?> ...`. >Feel free to add the answer, or as you say dupe it.

Comment: This should have been one of the first step to check, method/class declaration, instead you accused the IDE... that's quite rare to go that far ;)